# Unable to compile/link program after inclusion of opencv.hpp

Tags: opencv, linker-errors

I am trying to compile a program which uses opencv. I have included the opencv.hpp file in the .h and the .c file which needs the opencv functions. The project also has the properties set to use opencv. I am using 2.4.5 version of opencv. The problems I am facing is that after including these files in the project the project fails to compile. I get an error saying I have failed to #inlcude "stdafx.h". This is because I am using precompiled headers and #include"stdafx.h" has to be the first line of code in that .c or .cpp file. If I add the inclusion of stdafx.h tehn the program compiles but it does not link.

shown below is how i have included the files in the .c file.

**

```
include "../stdafx.h"
include "C:\opencv\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp"
include "DPD_AlgorithmInit.h"
```

**
and shown below is the inclusion in the .h file

```
include "C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h"
```

the error I am receiving is

```
error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\MOSS\PedestrianDetection\DPD_Tracker.c': No such file or directory C:\Users\sankalp\Desktop\check\MOSS_Evaluation\c1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _InitializeTracker C:\Users\sankalp\Desktop\check\MOSS\DPD_AlgorithmInit.obj error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DPD_Tracker C:\Users\sankalp\Desktop\check\MOSS\DPD_AlgorithmInit.obj error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned char * __cdecl DPD_Alloc(unsigned int)" (?DPD_Alloc@@YAPAEI@Z) C:\Users\sankalp\Desktop\check\MOSS\DPD_Tracker1.obj error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals C:\Users\sankalp\Desktop\check\Release\MOSS.exe
```

Am I doing something wrong while including the .hpp file? Is there a better way to include opencv to allow compilation and linking? I have tried toggling the precompiled header usage settings in the project too but It did not help.

Comment: To check if your build environment is setup correctly, go [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.5/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html#basic-linear-transform) and copy the source under the "Code" section and try to build it.

Comment: Thanks . The issue is resolved the problem was that the project was still searching for an old file [older version of a .cpp file]. somehow the vcxproj file was not updated. After adding stdafx and fixing the issue with vcxproj file it work fine.